# "xx.a uses VFP register arguments, yy.elf does not" on clean windows 10 install

Tags: c++, gcc, arm, xilinx

I have set up 2 identical windows 10 PC's where I have installed the Xilinx 2015.4 SDK. Only a single PC gives the following errors:

`c:/xilinx/sdk/2015.4/gnu/arm/nt/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-xilinx-eabi/4.9.2/../../../../arm-xilinx-eabi/bin/ld.exe: error: ../../standalone_bsp_0/ps7_cortexa9_0/lib\libxil.a(xgpio.o) uses VFP register arguments, framework.elf does not
c:/xilinx/sdk/2015.4/gnu/arm/nt/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-xilinx-eabi/4.9.2/../../../../arm-xilinx-eabi/bin/ld.exe: failed to merge target specific data of file ../../standalone_bsp_0/ps7_cortexa9_0/lib\libxil.a(xgpio.o)`

I have already tried adding the following flags:
`-mfloat-abi=hard -print-multi-lib` which causes the following errors:

`arm-xilinx-eabi-g++: error: ./src/Services/SOES/esc.o: No such file or directory
...
arm-xilinx-eabi-g++: error: ./src/main.o: No such file or directory
arm-xilinx-eabi-g++: error: ./src/platform.o: No such file or directory
arm-xilinx-eabi-g++: error: ./.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.o: No such file or directory`

Note that the other PC works perfectly fine with just the MinGW installation and no additional modifications to the SDK and toolchain configuration directly from our VCS repo.

Both windows installations have MinGW installed with the following packages.

- mingw32-base
- mingw32-gcc-g++

However the PC that's giving the errors had `mingw32-base` installed AFTER the errors appeared (small mistake).

Perhaps there is something wrong with the `PATH` variable?

Comment: so what are the PATH variables on the two PCs?  How do they differ?